# SQL Server Update Slow with Join

Tags: sql-server, join, sql-update

I have an sql update statement like so

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.Field = t2.Field
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.Key = t2.Key
WHERE t2.FilterField = 'abc'
```

The where clause makes it so that no rows are being updated the statement runs for 30 minutes. (The table has 50 million rows in it)

What is weird if I change the statement to

```
SELECT t1.Field, t2.Field
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.Key = t2.Key
WHERE t2.FilterField = 'abc'
```

An empty result set is returned pretty much instantly

If I change the statement to

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.Field = 1
FROM Table1 as t1
```

It updates the table in about 3 seconds.

I am really confused on what SQL Server is choking on an update statement that is not updating any records.

Comment: Check your execution plans

Comment: Is it getting caught up when trying to filter? Could a CROSS APPLY help - Change the inner join to `CROSS APPLY (SELECT Field FROM Table2 WHERE Key = t1.Key AND FilterField = 'abc') t2` and get rid of the `WHERE`

Comment: Can you provide the indexes you have on both tables? Is it as straightforward as you're presenting it? This isn't the simplified version of some dynamic SQL you're running from somewhere and passing in a variable for `'abc'`, right?

Comment: Also, are the tables on the same database and server (ie, not trying to update across a linked server)? And does any other process have one of the tables locked?

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar thing recently and our solution was:

```
UPDATE t1 SET t1.Field = t2.Field
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.Key = t2.Key
WHERE t2.FilterField = 'abc') t3
WHERE t1.key = t3.key
```

Where key is some form of uniquifier.  For us it is the ordering that was causing issues.  So another option would be an index.  That brought our 6 hour query down to roughly a minute.

Answer (score 0):

If timing's not an issue you could create separate update statements to run, like this, and see what happens:

```
SELECT 'UPDATE Table1 SET Field = ' + CAST(t2.Field as varchar(max)) + ' WHERE Key = ' + CAST(t1.[Key] as varchar(max))
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 on t1.[Key] = t2.[Key]
WHERE t2.FilterField = 'abc'
```